# How set size of specified String to JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

`JTextField` in `JPanel` which in turn in `JDialog` doesn't take specified size. I tried to use `BoxLayout` and `FlowLayout`, but still have not achieved the desired size. I.E. I measure the size of `String` `example` and set this size to width of `JTextField` `inputCat`, but `inputCat` doesn't take this size, then I call it. How correctly set size of specified `String` to `JTextField`?  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DemoJDialog {

    static private JInternalFrame internal;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoJDialog();
    }

    public DemoJDialog() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                internal = new JInternalFrame("Example", true, true, false, true);
                internal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                internal.setVisible(true);

                JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane();
                dp.add(internal);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(dp);
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);


                JTextField inputCat = new JTextField(); 


                String example = new String("Some very-very-very-"
                        + "very-very-very-very-very-very long string (really long )");
                int heightInputCat = inputCat.getSize().height;
                FontMetrics FN = internal.getFontMetrics(internal.getFont());
                int widthInputCat = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(FN, example);
                inputCat.setSize(widthInputCat, heightInputCat);



                String[] comboString = { "Telecast", "Radiocast" };
                JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(comboString);

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                SpinnerModel modelSpinner = new SpinnerDateModel(now.getTime(), 
                        null, null, Calendar.MONTH);
                final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(modelSpinner);
                spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DefaultEditor(spinner)); 

                JPanel listPane = new JPanel();
                listPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                listPane.add(comboBox);
                listPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
                listPane.add(inputCat);
                listPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
                listPane.add(spinner);

                Object[] array = {
                        new JLabel ("Enter a new category:"),
                        listPane
                };

                JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(array, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(internal, "Enter a new category:");
                dialog.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: I don't really understand the requirement or question (especially since there *was no question asked*) but note that `JTextField inputCat = new JTextField();` should better be `JTextField inputCat = new JTextField(10); // suggest a width in columns!`

Comment: Great links @Madhan.  :)

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow just following your footsteps @AndrewThompson

Comment: @Madhan Thanks and sorry for my lack of preparation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson maybe I should delete this incorreсt post?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks a lot. How correlate width in columns and width in pixels? In javadocs on docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html it is not explained. I.E. what exactly means width in columns?

Comment: *"How correlate width in columns and width in pixels?"*  It depends on the font and font size etc.  But you should never 'think in pixels' for building a Java GUI.  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: *"maybe I should delete this incorreсt post?"*  We'd prefer to see it [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30953133/edit) into a *great* question!  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556 - it's real hardcore for me for this moment, thanks :) I corrected question

Comment: It's a shame you did not correct the question to include an MCVE.  :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm really sorry, that I spend so much of your time. In what exactly I made a mistake? My example insufficiently minimal, or question is blurred?

Comment: *"My example insufficiently minimal,.."*  There is more to an MCVE than Minimal.  It has 3 other words and that uncompilable code snippet achieves *none* of them.  Note that the GUI thread I linked to includes an MCVE.  It is 4 'scroll downs' worth of code, so an MCVE can be **longer** than the code above.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, ok, so my example can not be execute by itself, i.e. does not correspond to paragraph COMPLETE. Am I right?

Comment: Right..  but since it is not Complete, we cannot Verify your results, and it is therefore not an Example (as meant by MCVE).

Comment: @AndrewThompson changed sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine here:

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DemoJDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoJDialog();
    }

    public DemoJDialog() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String example = new String("Some very-very-very-"
                        + "very-very-very-very-very-very "
                        + "long string (really long)");
                // create a textfield the size of the string!
                JTextField inputCat = new JTextField(example);
                inputCat.setCaretPosition(0);

                String[] comboString = {"Telecast", "Radiocast"};
                JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(comboString); 

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                SpinnerModel modelSpinner = new SpinnerDateModel(now.getTime(),
                        null, null, Calendar.MONTH);
                final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(modelSpinner);
                spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DefaultEditor(spinner));

                JPanel listPane = new JPanel();
                listPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                listPane.add(comboBox);
                listPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
                listPane.add(inputCat);
                listPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
                listPane.add(spinner);

                Object[] array = {
                    new JLabel("Enter a new category:"),
                    listPane
                };

                JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(array, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(listPane, "Enter a new category:");
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But `JTextField` is filled by the example `String`. And I need empty `JTextField` with this width

Answer (score 0):

> But JTextField is filled by the example String. And I need empty JTextField with this width

Just use constructor which specifies desired colums Count:

```
JTextField inputCat = new JTextField(example.length());
```